# Setting up Ant home in Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, ant, build

I have just installed Apache Ant and now, I am trying to set up ANT_HOME variable on Ubuntu OS and according to forums and solution founds in internet, there should require to edit the .bash_profile file in the root directory like follows:

```
ANT_HOME=/apache-install-dir/apache-ant-version
ANT_OPTS="-Xms256M -Xmx512M"
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin
export ANT_HOME ANT_OPTS PATH
```

But unfortunately I haven't found the  .bash_profile in my machine's root directory.

So, on this situation what should be the exact solution for my problem, any suggestion please please provide me, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If all users can use Ant, put your config in /etc/environment

For per-user setting, put to ~/.profile

Answer (score 1):

.bashrc file will be in the Home directory for that user (in your case it might be puru), if you specify these settings here it will be only available to you(current user for which you have modified .bashrc). For configuration for all available users you should place it in /etc/profile file. 
Note that .bashrc is a hidden file which you can see by pressing CTRL + H.

Comment: Ya, .bashrc file is found, I will try the setting on it. Thanks for the wonderful response Baggins. :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use a symbolic link to where you have installed Ant:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ ln -s /apache-install-dir/apache-ant-version/bin/ant ant
```

There's actually no need to set `$ANT_HOME` because it will be set automatically when the `ant` shell script is executed.

In fact, I put symbolic links to the `/usr/local/bin` directory for all of my tools, and for all of the newer versions of tools that we should be using over the versions that were installed on the OS.

Now, I can tell developers to put `/usr/local/bin` in their path and automatically get all of the tools that I've installed.

In fact, it might even be there by default. Even better, on some systems, the path is set by a program called `path_helper` that's called by `/etc/profile`. You setup a file with the basic paths that all developers should have by default, and developers will have that path automatically set.

> Unable to find a javac compiler;
>   com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
>   Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
>   It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre"

You might not have the Java Development Kit (JDK) installed on your system. Java has a JDK and a JRE (Java Runtime Engine). Make sure `$JAVA_HOME` is pointing to the JDK and not the JRE. It's very likely that `$JAVA_HOME` is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-adm64` See if there's a `bin` directory under that and that a program called `javac` is also there.

Again, I recommend putting symbolic links to all files in the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-adm64/bin` directory to `/usr/local/bin`. This way, developers won't have to add `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to their paths too.